# Is there a simple, universal outbound click tracking method for JQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, outbound, click-tracking

I'm looking for a way of tracking all outbound clicks from a web page using Javascript/ JQuery without modifying any of the existing page code. The solution must work with frames, iframes, content from different domains, AJAX etc.

Perhaps, Javascript is the wrong technology for a universal solution. If so, please let me know what would be better.

Comment: What browsers need to be supported?

Comment: I think you'd first have really identify and describe each way to leave the site and think about possibilities to track every way individually.

Comment: Hmmm, that's exactly what I want to avoid doing. I can specify that the user will be using an anchor tag to leave.

Comment: Would it be possible to record any click within the broswer window?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to capture all clicks on external links.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[@href^=http]").each(function(){
        if(this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
            // Handle click here
        }
    });
});
```

Getting this to work for iframes is a little trickier. The iframe should reside from the same domain due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If so you should be able to change the css selector above to something like `$("#iframe_id").contents().find("[@href^=http]")`

Comment: Need a solution that works for content originating from different domains.

Comment: Would this work if I used a PHP function like file_get_contents to get all the content onto the same domain?

Comment: You are talking serverside now ... i don't know what you are aiming for but no, the code i posted is pure clientside and can't capture serverside requests. That would require you to capture the requests serverside.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution:

```
get all a elements
    check href to see if it begins with http or https
        if so and the domain is external to your site, add a click handler
```

Comment: With getElementsByTagName() ?

Comment: What if the user is redirected to a different page a la `document.location = http://www.google.com`? What about posting to a form that returns a response or redirects to a new page?

Comment: Adding a click handler to each link is not a good idea. Better is to use *event delegation*.