# Is there a simple, universal outbound click tracking method for web pages?

Tags: php, statistics, web-analytics, outbound, click-tracking

I'm looking for a way of tracking all outbound clicks from a web page without modifying any of the existing page code. The solution must work with frames, iframes, content from different domains, AJAX etc.

I previously [posted about a Javascript / JQuery soluction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097695/is-there-a-simple-universal-outbound-click-tracking-method-for-jquery-javascri), but unfortunately the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) means Javascript won't work.

Comment: this is not possible. It cannot be done server-side because http is a stateless protocol and you don't have control over iframed content from different domains.  It would have to be done client-side and you already figured out even that is not possible. Bottom line is if you want to know this sort of thing, you have to have control over the content, including access to put page code on iframed content, and page code would have to be modified.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It cannot be done server-side because http is a stateless protocol and you don't have control over iframed content from different domains. It would have to be done client-side and you already figured out even that is not possible.

Bottom line is if you want to know this sort of thing, you have to have control over the content, including access to put page code on iframed content, and page code would have to be modified